# How to write runtime generated string into postgresql blob in java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, blob, inputstream

i am using for loop (million count) to generate some data on run-time. i like to save it into PostgreSQL DB as blob in single row, because holding all string in variable will occupies more RAM. How can i achieve this in java.

What i expect is:

```
 Open PostgreSQL connection
 For loop
  continuously save data to DB as blob
 End loop
 Close Connection
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer to [Chapter 7. Storing Binary Data](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html) of PostgreSQL JDBC documentation. Their example with `LargeObject` seem to be exactly what your are looking for:

```
// All LargeObject API calls must be within a transaction block
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

// Get the Large Object Manager to perform operations with
LargeObjectManager lobj = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).getLargeObjectAPI();

// Create a new large object
int oid = lobj.create(LargeObjectManager.READ | LargeObjectManager.WRITE);

// Later you will be able to access data loading it by `oid` identifier.
// Or you can save it's value to some row in database

// Open the large object for writing
LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.WRITE);

// Do your job here and stream the content
// Multiple obj.write calls expected

// Close the large object
obj.close();

// Finally, commit the transaction.
conn.commit();
```

But generally there is little sense in using such approach. Appending data to local file (temporary?) is a way more efficient.